# Closed local repository with a proxy connecter to a remote repository to control the Artifacts

Tags: maven, artifactory

My objective is to have control over the pulled artifacts through maven mirror option (settings.xml); therefore, I have create a local repository under JFrog but I need to link it to a remote repository using a proxy connector (disabled by default). Only one user will have write permissions on the local repository in a way when he wants to pull any artifact he will enable the proxy connector to the remote repository download the needed artifacts and disable the proxy connector once done.

Can anybody help me? To do the correct engineering/configuration under JFrog in order to achieve the above-described objective.

Answer (score 0):

Ziad - I believe that the offline option available with the remote repositories would be the best fit to achieve this special requirement.

> If a remote repository's offline checkbox is enabled, only artifacts from this repository
> that are already present in the cache are used. No further attempt
> will be made to fetch remote artifacts.

Reference: [JFrog Wiki: Remote repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Remote+Repositories#RemoteRepositories-SingleRepositoryOffline) (Single repository offline).